# How to determine if a certain property is invalid using the Spring MVC taglibs?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, bean-validation

I use JSR 303 to validate the the data send to my application. I have a controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        // ...
        return "users.index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/create", method = POST)
    public String create(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "users.form";
        }
        userService.addUser(userForm);
        return "redirect:users";
    }   
}
```

A `UserForm` class

```
public class UserForm {   
    private String email;

    // ...

    @Email
    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    // ...
}
```

And finally a `users.form.jsp` that uses the Spring form taglib to render a form.

```
<form:form action="users" method="post" commandName="userForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create User</legend>

        <div class="control-group">
            <form:label path="email">Email</form:label>
            <div class="controls">
                <form:input path="email"/>
                <form:errors path="email" cssClass="help-inline" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <%-- More Fields, Buttons --%>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

I want to add a CSS-class to to `div.control-group`. Is this possible using the Spring MVC form taglib? How can I determine if a property of a bean is invalid in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the Spring `bind` tag. You can access the binding status through `${status}` and can query if there was an error through `${status.error}`. This results in the following snippet:

```
<form:form action="users" method="post" commandName="userForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create User</legend>

        <spring:bind path="email">
            <c:if test="${status.error}"><c:set var="classes">error</c:set></c:if>
            <div class="control-group ${classes}">
                <form:label path="email">Email</form:label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <form:input path="email"/>
                    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="help-inline" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <%-- More Fields, Buttons --%>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```